# How to make buttons change on different click amounts java

Tags: java, jbutton, actionlistener

I am trying to make a game in java where if you click on a button once it turns red, and if you click on it twice it turns blue, but I'm running into an issue where when I click one square once and it becomes red, if I click another once it turns blue, when I want the effect isolated to each square at a time(e.g. if I click one square once its red, click another twice its blue, and another square once its red). I also want it to reset after 3 clicks.

Here is my actions listener so far

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame(); //creates frame
JButton[][] grid; //names the grid of buttons

int clicked = 0;

public ButtonGrid(int width, int length) { //constructor
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(width, length)); //set layout
    grid = new JButton[width][length]; //allocate the size of grid
    for(int y = 0; y < length; y++) {
        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            grid[x][y] = new JButton(); //creates a button
            grid[x][y].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        if(clicked == 0) {
        ((JButton)e.getSource()).setBackground(Color.red);
                            clicked++;
                        } else if(clicked == 1) {
        ((JButton)e.getSource()).setBackground(Color.blue);
                            clicked++;
                        }
                    }
            });
            frame.add(grid[x][y]); //adds new button to grid
        }
    }
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack(); //sets appropriate size for frame
    frame.setVisible(true); //makes frame visible
// ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your current implementation, `clicked` is a instance field of the parent class, which all your buttons/`ActionListener`s are using.

Instead, you need to isolate the property so that it can be better associated with a single button.

Now, you could create a custom class which `extends` from `JButton`, but IMHO, that's a little heavy handed and locks you into a single use case.  Personally, I'd look towards implementating a concrete implementation of the `ActionListener` to provide this side effect.

For example...

```
public class CounterActionListener implements ActionListener {
    private int counter;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object source = e.getSource();
        if (source instanceof JButton) {
            JButton button = (JButton)source;
            clicked++;
            if(clicked == 0) {
                button.setBackground(Color.red);
            } else if(clicked == 1){
                button.setBackground(Color.blue);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your code, you just apply the listener to the button, for example...

```
grid[x][y] = new JButton(new CounterActionListener());
```

You could also follow this by making use of a "delegate", which actually performed the required operations, based on the number of clicks, which could be held in a model, but that's beyond the scope of the question ;)

Comment: What is btn used for? And where would this get placed in my code?

Comment: @GregoryWeigel Sorry, copy and pasted code directly into the answer. *"And where would this get placed in my code?"* would relate to *"Then in your code, you just apply the listener to the button, for example..."* - the actual `CounterActionListener` is just a class, so it would be placed anywhere in your source you felt appropriate

Answer (score 1):

You have one global clicked for all of them. Because of that actions are not isolated.

int clicked = 0;

Shouldnt be in class.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `clicked` is attached to the frame, not to the button.  That means that there is only a single value of `clicked` for your entire application.

The easiest thing to do here would be to write a new class `GregoryWeigelButton` (or whatever) which `extends JButton` and has a `int clicked=0` inside it (and probably a getter and setter).  Then just check what the `clicked` value for *that particular button* is.

Comment: Actually, the OP should be implementing the `ActionListener` as dedicated class

Comment: I don't think I follow you.  Are you suggesting using the `ActionListener` to check the button's colour?  It seemed to me the number of times it had been clicked on was an attribute of the button, not the listener.

Comment: What I'm suggesting is, instead of extending from `JButton`, you use a dedicated `ActionListener` (with a `counter` property, possibly seeded with the required colors).  The `ActionListener` can then take the `source` from the `ActionEvent` and if it's a button, apply the required logic to it. This would then allow you to use `JToggleButton` or `JCheckBox` as well, rather then locking you into a single use case of a custom `JButton` - it would also allow you to re-use the `ActionListener` implementation on pre-existing buttons without having to change the code significantly

Comment: *"to me the number of times it had been clicked on was an attribute of the button, not the listener"* - I would argue that's a side effect of the implementation - but that's me ;)

Comment: Honestly I'm still not convinced.  The using `JToggleButton` etc is a good point and one I hadn't thought of.  But I'm not sure how much code rewriting there would have to be, and doing it through the `ActionListener` would seem to prevent doing other stuff through there, every such button would have the same actions.  But something to think about, thanks for that.

Comment: Guess I just prefer composition of inheritance and have found my self coded into a inheritance corner to many times :P

Comment: LOL, touche.  Have a plus one before I go to bed.  I do still feeling you're locking yourself in to a single use case albeit just in a different way, the more I think about it the answer is probably an interface.  But its nearly midnight and "thinking about it" is hard.

Comment: I won't say your approach is "wrong", but in my experience it's a starting point for a downward spiral of issues. In this "particular" case, it probably won't be an issue, I just find that using a `ActionListener` and more "preferred" mechanism.  Add to it a model and delegate and you could have a very flexible solution - IMHO